# Cannot find module "fs" - at webpackMissingModule

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

My server starts and runs correctly, but when I hit the URL in the browser it gives an error "cannot find module 'fs'".

I tried to setting:

1. target: 'node', but it starts another error
2. node: { fs: 'empty' }, but then it gives an error "cannot find exports"

   ```
   "use strict";

   const webpack = require('webpack');
   const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
   const DEBUG = !argv.release;

   const path = require('path');

   var plugins = [
     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
       names: ['common', 'vendors'],
       filename: '[name].js',
       minChunks: Infinity
     }),
     new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env.NODE_ENV':  DEBUG ? '"development"' : '"production"',
       "process.argv.verbose": !!DEBUG
     }),
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery",
       jquery: "jquery"
     })
   ].concat(DEBUG ? [] : [
     new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
       minimize: true,
       compress: {
         warnings: true
       }
     }),
     new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
   ]);

   module.exports = {
     entry: {
       app: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'app.js'),
       vendors: [
         'react',
         'react-dom',
         'react-bootstrap',
         'react-router',
         'alt',
         'lodash',
         'superagent',
         'react-router-role-authorization',
         'react-validation-decorator'
       ]
     },

     output: {
       publicPath: '/js/',
       path: './wwwroot/js/',
       filename: '[name].js',
       chunkFilename: "[id].[name].js"
     },

     context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),

     plugins: plugins,

     cache: DEBUG,
     debug: DEBUG,
     watch: DEBUG,

     stats: {
       colors: true
     },

     resolve: {
       extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
     },

     module: {
       loaders: [
         {
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loaders: ['babel-loader']
         },
         {
           test: /\.(less|css)$/,
           loaders: ["style", "css", "less"]
         },
         {
           test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
           loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
         },
         {
           test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3|mp4)$/,
           loader: 'file-loader'
         },
         {
           test: /\.json$/,
           loader: 'json-loader'
         }
       ]
     },
     node: {
       net: 'mock',
       dns: 'mock'
     }
   };
   ```

It should not give this error and work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any mention of the `fs` module in your posted webpack setup. So, my guess is that your output application (`app.js`?) is trying to require and use `fs`. Webpack is building a client-side, front-end application, one that will be loaded in the browser; `fs` is *not available* in the browser.

(Double-check and make sure you aren't trying to, for example, read and write files on the user's machine using `fs` inside your client-side application. That is not possible in a browser-based application. For an intro to the concept of web applications with a front end and back end, check out the article [React App With Node Backend](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0).)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to require a module of back-end in front-end